# gearman php do not exit and memory exhausted

Tags: php, gearman

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
$gmworker= new GearmanWorker();
$gmworker->addServer();
$gmworker->addFunction("create_job_process", "worker_create_job");
$gmworker->setTimeout(-1);

print "Waiting for job...\n";
while($gmworker->work())
{
  if ($gmworker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
  {
    echo "return_code: " . $gmworker->returnCode() . "\n";
    break;
  }
  if ($gmworker->returnCode() == GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
  {
    echo "success\n\n";
    break;
  }
  sleep(1);
}
```

When the "success" show in log, i can see the memory usage growing then got the error:

PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 24 bytes)

Comment: Hmm, if the success message is displayed, the while loop will be exit. So why do you say in the title it will not exit? You want to probably use `die()` instead of break to make it really exit on success.

Comment: I used break, exit, no difference

Comment: If you echo $gmworker->returnCode(), what value is it spitting out while in the while loop? Is there any possibility that the mem leak is in your worker_create_job function?

Comment: Does `returnCode()`? give anything else beyond `GERMAN_SUCCESS`. Maybe since the returnCode is called twice it allocates a variable for some reason (and the second time this triggers a memory error). Possibly try if/else instead of if/if.

Comment: @Eric Caron: I saw success first, then the memory grow, so i think the gearman do something caused the memory growing.

Comment: Which line in the code of your question is actually giving the error message? Can you please highlight it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if ($ret == GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
  {
    echo "success\n";
    //force to quit
    exec("kill -9 ". getmypid());
    die();
  }
```

Finally added the exec("kill -9 ". getmypid()); to stop the process.